# jQuery - How can I add a class for a single div containing a checkbox relative to the checked box?

Tags: jquery

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox-wrap">
      <p>Check this: 
      <input type="checkbox" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox-wrap">
      <p>Check this: 
      <input type="checkbox" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="checkbox-wrap">
      <p>Check this: 
      <input type="checkbox" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery:

```
$this('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('div.checkbox-wrap').addClass("active-checkbox");
    } else {
        $('div.checkbox-wrap').removeClass("active-checkbox");
    }
});
```

When you check a checkbox the class "active-checkbox" is being added to the whole 3 divs.
Is there any way to add the class for a single div and not for the whole 3 divs without using ID or custom class names ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrongly put `$this('input:checkbox')` instead of  `$('input:checkbox')`, you can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the first occurance of selector in up in ancestor hierarchy.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/xxyEL/1/)**

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){       
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('div.checkbox-wrap').addClass("active-checkbox");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('div.checkbox-wrap').removeClass("active-checkbox");
    }
});​
```

Comment: I should look up on the "closest" documentation. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `closest` to find the nearest `.checkbox-wrap` element:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        $checkbox.closest('div.checkbox-wrap').addClass("active-checkbox");
    } else {
        $checkbox.closest('div.checkbox-wrap').removeClass("active-checkbox");
    }
});
```

More information on [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Also, I assume `$this` at the start is an aliased version of jQuery, and not a typo?

Comment: What should be used here more perfect either `closest` or `parents`?

Comment: In this case `closest`. The difference is `parents()` get **all** elements matching the selector, `closest()` gets the **first** element matching the selector

Comment: Don't worry, I have a feeling I know who it was.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:eq()` Selector to do this as

```
$(".checkbox-wrap:eq(0)").addClass("active-checkbox");
```

Check [This](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) out

Answer (score 0):

```
$this('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   $(this).parents('div.checkbox-wrap').toggleClass("active-checkbox", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```